# updating raspberry pi with docker containers running

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I recently started using docker on raspberry pi. I am using a set of docker containers that are run constantly e.g. pihole, node red, mosquitto etc. I know that if you have to restart raspberry pi then you should stop the containers first and then restart them once the pi has rebooted. But in some other tutorials I see they check for update by using the command sudo apt updates for the raspberry pi OS and install the updates if they are available. I want to know the following:

Should I stop the containers before checking and installing updates for the raspberry pi OS?

do you need to stop all the containers that depend on each other before updating any one of the container or just stop the container that needs to be updated?

Comment: Are you using compose for them? If not, then you should shut the required containers first, then the others. But you can run `sudo apt-get update` without needing to stop the containers, but sometimes security patches can require a restart

Comment: yes there is a docker compose file. So I suppose I don't need to stop the container before updating the container?

Comment: If you want to update the container then yes you will need to stop them to update their image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I stop the containers before checking and installing updates for the raspberry pi OS?

Generally, no, updates on the host won't have any impact on your containers. The exception is if you install an update to Docker, which may restart the Docker daemon. This can cause all your containers to exit, although they will come back up automatically if you have configured them with a restart policy. And of course a kernel update will require a host reboot before it becomes active.

> do you need to stop all the containers that depend on each other before updating any one of the container or just stop the container that needs to be updated?

This really depends on how you have designed your applications.

Consider a web application that talks to a database. If you were to remove the database container and create a new one with updated software or configuration, depending on how the web application is written:

- It might crash, requiring you to restart it manually.
- If you have configured it with a restart policy, Docker might take care of restarting it for you.
- If the application has reconnect/retry logic, it might simply wait until the database is back up and available.
- The application itself might require an update before it is able to run correctly.

It's up to you to understand that dependencies in your software stack and determine how best to handle component upgrades.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer.  Regarding the dependencies, I haven't designed these applications or rather the combination of apps that I am using. It's someone else's designed stack and I just use their docker compose file. However, lately I saw newer docker images and was wondering how can I update the images safely. I only have a single raspberry pi which I am using to both learn/experiment and as a webserver.

Comment: But I do get the logic of dependencies in my application suite. I believe in my case it would be best to stop the stack , update and then restart the containers